pyspark dataframe: Select columns from Struct based based on pattern and pivot
I am working on a vendor provided dataset with unstructured columns. The column is struct type with multiple key-value pairs.
example:



ID
Type
Data




1
Day
{Day_1:'Monitor', Day_2:'Manage', Evening_6:'None', Evening_3:'Monitor'}


2
Evening
{Day_2:'N/A', Day_3:'None', Evening_1:'On Call', Evening_2:'On Call'}


3
Day
{Day_1:'Manage', Day_5:'On Call', Evening_2:'None'}



I need to give it an structure for querying. Based on the Type column, find the corresponding shifts from the Data struct columns and then pivot them to separate rows by splitting the key on underscore.
So, the output should look like this:



ID
Type
Shift
Role




1
Day
1
Monitor


1
Day
2
Manage


2
Evening
1
On Call


2
Evening
2
On Call


3
Day
1
Manage


3
Day
5
On Call



I am working in pyspark and trying to do this as follows:

Form a regex using Type column value + '_' + number
Select columns from struct 'Data' column using the regexp_extract.
Convert columns to rows using explode function
Split on underscore in the value of column name and keep the 2nd index value.

I am new to pyspark and would like some help in implementing this.

To parse the Day_*: data use regex:
/(?<=(Day\_\d+\:)(\')?)[\w+\/]+(?=(\')?)/gi


sample: regex_101

Similarly to parse Evening_*: data use regex:
/(?<=(Evening\_\d+\:)(\')?)[\w+\/]+(?=(\')?)/gi

sample: regex_101
